# Declare variable to return Json result (ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is action from my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AjaxAction]
public ActionResult Registration(RegisterUserModel registerUser)
{
    var data;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!IsUserExist(registerUser.Email))
        {    

            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

            var encrpPass = crypto.Compute(registerUser.Password);

            var newUser = _db.Users.Create();

            newUser.Name = registerUser.Name;
            newUser.Email = registerUser.Email;
            newUser.Type = UserType.User.ToString();

            newUser.Password = encrpPass;
            newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;

            _db.Users.Add(newUser);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            data = new { status = "OK", message = "Success" };

        }
        else
        {

            data = new { status = "ERROR", message = "User already exists" };
        }
    }
    else
    {

        data = new { status = "ERROR", message = "Data is incorrect" };
    }
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

but I don't know how to initialize `data` variable in the right way, because I need to set different values in different cases. What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use multiple `return` statements to avoid having to declare an object like

```
if(something){
return Json(new{status = "status 1", message = "message1"})
}
else{
return Json(new{status = "status 2", message = "message2"})
}
```

Comment: just an FYI.  the else statement isn't needed if can be written
            if (true)
            {
                return 'whatever'
            }

            return 'whatever';

Comment: @Fran great notice, but actually I don't like to have multiple returns in my actions, I prefer to have the one. Maybe I'm not right.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
var data = new object();
```

Comment: how do you populate the status and message property with an object

Comment: As far, as I know, there are no public properties available with `System.Object`

Comment: And also, the code would not compile if you initialize data as object and then assign it an anonymous object with two properties. Dot Net creates types for anonymous objects on the fly

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the options

```
[HttpPost]
[AjaxAction]
public ActionResult Registration(RegisterUserModel registerUser)
{
    JsonResult data;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!IsUserExist(registerUser.Email))
        {    

            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

            var encrpPass = crypto.Compute(registerUser.Password);

            var newUser = _db.Users.Create();

            newUser.Name = registerUser.Name;
            newUser.Email = registerUser.Email;
            newUser.Type = UserType.User.ToString();

            newUser.Password = encrpPass;
            newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;

            _db.Users.Add(newUser);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            data = Json(new { status = "OK", message = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        else
        {

            data = Json(new { status = "ERROR", message = "User already exists"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    else
    {

        data = Json(new { status = "ERROR", message = "Data is incorrect" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, interesting idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword.

```
dynamic data;
```